# Embedding Flash in a Report Viewer .NET app using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, shockwave

I was told to Embed a flash control inside a report viewer so that when user clicks on the generate report button instead of displaying that green circle a small animation clip will be played. I know how to how to customized the green circle and put my own image but is it possible to Shockwave flash control inside report viewer. Sine we are manipulating the report viewer control so we have to  create the Shockwave flash object at runtime and add the control to the report viewer.

Code:-

```
AxShockwaveFlash flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();

            flash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            flash.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            flash.Enabled = true;
            flash.Movie = "http://www.abd.com/file.swf";

            reportviewer.Controls.Add(flash);
```

But this is not woking.

Comment: "This is not working" doesn't tell much about your problem. If it worked, you (most likely) weren't here.

Comment: ya that's wright. Actually i wana know how to create AxShockwaveFlash dynamically and add it to my report viewer. I am trying it for so long and giving Invalid Active State Exceptions all the time.

Comment: If you want help it would be a good start to post the actual error message you are getting...

Comment: You know that green circle starts when we generate report. I want to replace it with a AxShockwaveFlash. So that when user generates reports instead of that green circle a small flash clip can be played.

Comment: I can tell that much from the text of your question (and from your first comment). What interests me is the _actual `Exception`_ you are getting from the above code.

Comment: i tried the above code.But in line number 5. its giving the error Invalid Active State Exceptions and the control is not binding to the report viewer. So i want to know how exactly AxShockwaveFlash objects are bind dynamically. If i drag and drop in the form it works fine. Any idea

Comment: this is the exact exception System.Windows.Form.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException

Comment: No. That is the _type_ of the exception. The _exact_ exception would be something like `System.ArgumentException: "Please post the whole error you're getting." at [insert stack trace here]` (¬_¬) btw: It's not an Active State Exception but an ActiveX State Exception you're getting. That `X` is important.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6757/discussion-between-aaraadhana-and-tobias)